# Get textbox binding in wpf datagridtemplatecolumn

Tags: wpf, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a wpf datagrid containing multiple datagridtemplatecolumns, which all are build up from a datatemplate which contains a textbox.

Now I want to get the binding of the textbox (I have a reference to the template column which textbox's binding  I woukld like to determine).

Alternatively it would be nice to return the X:Name of the template column

Any hints?
Regards
klaus

Answer (score 0):

Use [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) to travers the grid and find all text boxes (e.g. by name) and then use [GetBindingExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.getbindingexpression.aspx) to get the bindig:  `control.GetBindingExpression(control.TextProperty)`